# What years/year ranges in the Forgotten Realms correspond to what D&D editions?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, forgotten-realms, time

The current edition of D&D (5th) has adventures in the Forgotten Realms set in 1489-1493 DR.

During what years in the Forgotten Realms are adventures from each edition set?

(Answers should include 5th edition, for completeness)

Comment: [Zwiq's answer here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/129070/28402) about edition-changing events in FR might be helpful related reading.

Comment: Related: [What events in Forgotten Realms lore marked transitions from one edition to another?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/45815/33569)

Answer (score 16):

The AD&D 1st Edition *Forgotten Realms Campaign Set* (Gray Box) is set at the start of 1358 DR.¹

The AD&D 2nd Edition *Forgotten Realms Campaign Setting* box is set at the start of 1368 DR.²

The D&D 3rd Edition *Forgotten Realms Campaign Setting* book is set in 1372 DR.³

The D&D 4th Edition *Forgotten Realms Campaign Guide* book is set in 1479 DR.⁴

The D&D 5th Edition *Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide* book  is set at the start of 1490 DR.⁵ The adventure *Princes of the Apocalypse* is set in 1491,⁶ and *Waterdeep: Dragon Heist* in 1492.⁷

---

**References:**

¹ ‘Special Calendar Days’, *Cyclopedia of the Realms*, Forgotten Realms Campaign Set (TSR, 1987), p6.

² ‘Marking the Years’, *A Grand Tour of the Realms*, Forgotten Realms Campaign Setting (TSR, 1993), p.22.

³ ‘The Roll of Years’, *Forgotten Realms Campaign Setting* (Wizards of the Coast, 2001), p.78.

⁴ ‘Your Campaign in 1479 DR’, *Forgotten Realms Campaign Guide* (Wizards of the Coast, 2008), p.40.

⁵ ‘The Present Age’, *Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide* (Wizards of the Coast, 2015), pp.17–18.

⁶‘Time in the Realms’, *Elemental Evil: Princes of the Apocalypse* (Wizards of the Coast, 2015), p.19.

⁷ Christopher Perkins [@ChrisPerkinsDnD], 2018, Nov 8. *1492 DR, the Year of Three Ships Sailing (I kid you not). #wotcstaff #SeaMaidensFaire* [Tweet]. [Twitter](https://twitter.com/ChrisPerkinsDnD/status/1060352777174560769?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw%7Ctwcamp%5Etweetembed%7Ctwterm%5E1060352777174560769%7Ctwgr%5E%7Ctwcon%5Es1_&ref_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.sageadvice.eu%2Fany-idea-if-waterdeep-dragon-heist-takes-place-in-1492-dr-or-1491-dr%2F).